# Selección filtrada de 3 tablas

Tags: mysql

tengo la duda de cómo puedo realizar una selección filtrada de tres tablas en MySQL, las tablas están relacionadas no son independientes.

Comment: Coloca la estructura de tus tablas y una muestra de cómo esperas salgan los resultados

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). E incorpora el código de tus intentos. Preferimos enseñarte a pescar que darte peces, si vemos lo que has intentado, podremos ayudarte a mejorar. Aquí se explica mucho mejor: [ask] Bienvendo a [so]